# Loop over json objects in Ansible

Tags: json, loops, ansible

I have been stuck to get a particular json object if the value of a key matches a variable (string).

My json file looks like this:

```
    "totalRecordsWithoutPaging": 1234,
    "jobs": [
        {
            "jobSummary": {

                "totalNumOfFiles": 0,
                "jobId": 8035,
                "destClientName": "BOSDEKARLSSP010",
                "destinationClient": {
                    "clientId": 10,
                    "clientName": "BOSDEKARLSSP010"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "jobSummary": {
                "totalNumOfFiles": 0,
                "jobId": 9629,
                "destClientName": "BOSDEKARLSSP006",
                "destinationClient": {
                    "clientId": 11,
                    "clientName": "BOSDEKARLSSP006"
                }
            }
        },
                .....
    ]
}
```

I read this json with `result: "{{ lookup('file','CVExport-short.json') | from_json }}"` and I can get only one value of `destClientName` key with the following code:

```
- name: Iterate JSON
  set_fact:
    app_item: "{{ item.jobSummary }}"
  with_items: "{{ result.jobs }}"
  register: app_result

- debug:
    var: app_result.results[0].ansible_facts.app_item.destClientName
```

My goal is to get the value of `jobId`if the value of `destClientName` matches some other variable or string in any `jobSummary`.
I don't still have much knowledge in Ansible. So, any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

Ok, I have found one solution.

```
- name: get job ID
  set_fact: 
    job_id: "{{ item.jobSummary.jobId }}"
  with_items: "{{ result.jobs}}"
  when: item.jobSummary.destClientName == '{{ target_vm }}'

- debug: 
    msg: "{{job_id}}"
```

But I think there might be a better solution than this. Any idea how?

Comment: Ok, I have found one solution. ```- name: get job ID
  set_fact:
    job_id: "{{ item.jobSummary.jobId }}"
  with_items: "{{ result.jobs}}"
  when: item.jobSummary.destClientName == '{{ target_vm }}'
- debug:
    msg: "{{job_id}}"``` . But is I think, there might be a better solution than this. Any idea how?

Comment: It is better to edit your question to add that sort of information (because then you can properly format the task, which makes it much easier for other people to read).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ansible's [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter let's you perform complex filtering of JSON documents by applying [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) expressions.  Rather than looping over the jobs in the the result, you can get the information you want in a single step.

We want to query all jobs in which have a `destClientName` that matches the value in `target_vm`.  Using literal values, the expression yielding that list of jobs would look like this:

```
jobs[?jobSummary.destClientName == `BOSDEKARLSSP006`]
```

The result of this, when applied to your sample data, would be:

```
[
  {
    "jobSummary": {
      "totalNumOfFiles": 0,
      "jobId": 9629,
      "destClientName": "BOSDEKARLSSP006",
      "destinationClient": {
        "clientId": 11,
        "clientName": "BOSDEKARLSSP006"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

From this result, you want to extract the `jobId`, so we rewrite the expression like this:

```
jobs[?jobSummary.destClientName == `BOSDEKARLSSP006`]|[0].jobSummary.jobId
```

Which gives us:

```
9629
```

To make this work in a playbook, you'll want to replace the literal hostname in this expression with the value of your `target_vm` variable.   Here's a complete playbook that demonstrates the solution:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  # This is just the sample data from your question.
  vars:
    target_vm: BOSDEKARLSSP006
    results:
      totalRecordsWithoutPaging: 1234
      jobs:
      - jobSummary:
          totalNumOfFiles: 0
          jobId: 8035
          destClientName: BOSDEKARLSSP010
          destinationClient:
            clientId: 10
            clientName: BOSDEKARLSSP010
      - jobSummary:
          totalNumOfFiles: 0
          jobId: 9629
          destClientName: BOSDEKARLSSP006
          destinationClient:
            clientId: 11
            clientName: BOSDEKARLSSP006

  tasks:
    - name: get job ID
      set_fact:
        job_id: "{{ results|json_query('jobs[?jobSummary.destClientName == `{}`]|[0].jobSummary.jobId'.format(target_vm)) }}"

    - debug:
        var: job_id
```

---

**Update** re: your comment

The `{}` in the expression is a Python string formatting sequence that
is filled in by the call to `.format(target_vm)`.  In Python, the
expression:

```
'The quick brown {} jumped over the lazy {}.'.format('fox', 'dog')
```

Would evaluate to:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

And that's exactly what we're doing in that `set_fact` expression.  I
could instead have written:

```
job_id: "{{ results|json_query('jobs[?jobSummary.destClientName == `' ~ target_vm ~ '`]|[0].jobSummary.jobId') }}"
```

(Where `~` is the Jinja stringifying concatenation operator)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works. I could follow you till ```jobs[?jobSummary.destClientName == `BOSDEKARLSSP006`]|[0].jobSummary.jobId```. However I couldn't understand ```{}``` in the final query.

Comment: I've left an update that hopefully help out with that.